# Gitlab Closed Merge Requests 500 Error

Tags: git, gitlab

When trying to filter the merge request by closed or all I get redirected to a 500 error page. I did just do an upgrade and I'm wondering if the old merge requests might be an issue. I've done a select against the table because I think that there are some null values in there that aren't suppose to be.

```
+----+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+------------------+-------------------+------+------------------------+
| id | target_branch   | source_branch      | source_project_id | author_id | assignee_id | title                                | created_at          | updated_at          | milestone_id | state  | merge_status     | target_project_id | iid  | description            |
+----+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+------------------+-------------------+------+------------------------+
|  1 | master          | 139529-aaa-changes |                 3 |         1 |           2 | Merging aaa changes back into master | 2014-03-11 23:31:26 | 2014-03-11 23:32:32 |         NULL | closed | unchecked        |                 3 | NULL | NULL                   |
|  2 | master          | 139529-aaa-changes |                 3 |         1 |           2 | Merging aaa changes back into master | 2014-03-11 23:33:34 | 2014-03-18 15:06:08 |         NULL | merged | unchecked        |                 3 | NULL | NULL                   |
|  3 | master          | floodlight-tag     |                 3 |         1 |           2 | Floodlight Tag                       | 2014-03-17 20:54:12 | 2014-03-21 18:37:52 |         NULL | closed | cannot_be_merged |                 3 | NULL | NULL                   |
|  4 | release         | AffiliateSitesTest |                 5 |         1 |           1 | test                                 | 2014-03-17 20:59:42 | 2014-03-17 20:59:51 |         NULL | closed | unchecked        |                 5 | NULL | NULL                   |
|  5 | master_20140321 | jsoptimization     |                 3 |         1 |           1 | Jsoptimization                       | 2014-03-22 23:25:53 | 2014-03-22 23:26:45 |         NULL | closed | unchecked        |                 3 |    1 |                        |
|  6 | master_20140321 | floodlight-tag     |                 3 |         1 |           1 | Floodlight Tag                       | 2014-03-22 23:28:40 | 2014-03-22 23:29:22 |         NULL | closed | cannot_be_merged |                 3 |    2 |                        |
|  7 | stable          | packagedates       |                 3 |         2 |           1 | Packagedates                         | 2014-03-24 18:56:04 | 2014-03-25 16:56:56 |         NULL | merged | unchecked        |                 3 |    3 | Merge into stable      |
|  8 | stable          | floodlight-tag     |                 3 |         1 |           1 | Floodlight Tag                       | 2014-03-24 19:24:54 | 2014-03-24 19:25:07 |         NULL | closed | cannot_be_merged |                 3 |    4 | testing                |
|  9 | master_20140321 | release            |                 3 |         1 |           1 | Release                              | 2014-03-25 17:45:21 | 2014-03-25 17:46:24 |            2 | closed | cannot_be_merged |                 3 |    5 |                        |
| 10 | master          | release            |                 3 |         1 |           1 | Release                              | 2014-03-25 19:26:20 | 2014-03-25 19:26:47 |         NULL | closed | can_be_merged    |                 3 |    6 | Testing                |
| 11 | release         | master             |                 3 |         1 |           1 | Master                               | 2014-03-25 19:27:31 | 2014-03-25 19:28:51 |         NULL | closed | unchecked        |                 3 |    7 | @akislenko
```

I've looked through the logs and I think this log entry is related:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects/merge_requests", :project_id=>#<Project id: 5, name: "Affiliate Sites", path: "affiliate-sites", description: nil, created_at: "2013-07-29 14:56:01", updated_at: "2013-07-29 15:07:20", creator_id: 1, issues_enabled: true, wall_enabled: false, merge_requests_enabled: true, wiki_enabled: true, namespace_id: 5, issues_tracker: "gitlab", issues_tracker_id: nil, snippets_enabled: false, last_activity_at: "2014-03-17 20:59:51", import_url: nil, visibility_level: 0, archived: false, import_status: "none">, :id=>#<MergeRequest id: 4, target_branch: "release", source_branch: "AffiliateSitesTest", source_project_id: 5, author_id: 1, assignee_id: 1, title: "test", created_at: "2014-03-17 20:59:42", updated_at: "2014-03-17 20:59:51", milestone_id: nil, state: "closed", merge_status: "unchecked", target_project_id: 5, iid: nil, description: nil>, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
    1: %li{ class: mr_css_classes(merge_request) }
    2:   .merge-request-title
    3:     %span.light= "##{merge_request.iid}"
    4:     = link_to_gfm truncate(merge_request.title, length: 80), project_merge_request_path(merge_request.target_project, merge_request), class: "row_title"
    5:     - if merge_request.merged?
    6:       %small.pull-right
    7:         %i.icon-ok
  app/views/projects/merge_requests/_merge_request.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_projects_merge_requests__merge_request_html_haml__889413478871945037_70150652521800'
  app/views/shared/_merge_requests.html.haml:10:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_shared__merge_requests_html_haml___4127460965921930050_70150652354320'
  app/views/shared/_merge_requests.html.haml:9:in `each'
  app/views/shared/_merge_requests.html.haml:9:in `block in _app_views_shared__merge_requests_html_haml___4127460965921930050_70150652354320'
  app/views/shared/_merge_requests.html.haml:2:in `each'
  app/views/shared/_merge_requests.html.haml:2:in `_app_views_shared__merge_requests_html_haml___4127460965921930050_70150652354320'
  app/views/dashboard/merge_requests.html.haml:13:in `_app_views_dashboard_merge_requests_html_haml___2670017937016338979_70150653186460'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:58:in `set_current_user_for_thread'
```

It looks like the null iid might be the culprit here?